# Charge stored in a capacitor with dielectric when relative permittivity varies

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, capacitance

Suppose the relative permittivity of the dielectric in an uncharged capacitor of capacitance C varies with the voltage applied, e.g. k=xV where x has dimensions of V^-1 (After this capacitor is given a potential difference). If I connect this capacitor to a charged capacitor with some capacitance C', charge will flow from the charged capacitor to the uncharged one and I would like to find the value of this charge.

My question is whether the equation dQ=Cdv is valid here (The way I interpret it is that for small addition of charge there is a small change in potential difference).

If it is, then the final charge flown should be Q= x(CV^2)/2 which is wrong according to a few problems I solved. The correct answer is given as Q=xCV^2.

What went wrong?

Comment: "Suppose the relative permittivity of the dielectric in an uncharged capacitor of capacitance C varies with the voltage applied, e.g. k=xV " Not sure what this means. How can the permittivity  of an UNCHARGED capacitor vary with voltage?   If there is a voltage across the capacitor, it is by definition charged. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well, it's definitely going to vary after they are connected. That's probably the only thing you can guess if no extra information is provided.

Comment: Then why say uncharged capacitor? You should edit that qualifier out.

Comment: It simply means that the relative permittivity varies after the uncharged capacitor is connected with the charged one, so no variation before this. I have made an edit in the wording now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i think I figured it out myself.

So the problem is when you differentiate Q=VC, you also get another term which i was missing.

The correct equation should be dQ = CdV + VdC

and now it's quite easy to get the correct result.